# Haskell search path? Or how to access source files from doc/test folder?

Tags: haskell

I set up a project according to the recommendation here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Structure_of_a_Haskell_project

How can I run an example in the doc/examples folder? Assume I have `src/App/SomeModule.hs`, and `doc/examples/Example1.hs`. Example1 has a main method, and `import App.SomeModule`. Of course, when I try to compile or run Example1 it dies because it can't find `App.SomeModule`.

How do you solve this problem? Is there some kind of search path mechanism where I can tell ghc to look in the other folder for files? Do you do anything different for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, `$ ghc doc/examples/Example1 -i src/`. You can also have a `.cabal` file in `doc/examples` with `hs-source-dirs: ../../src` for example.

Comment: I've tried the first option. It works with ghc. Is there a way to get it to work with runghc?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: `-i` should work with `runghc` as well, just make sure you put it _before_ the module name, since everything after that is treated as arguments to your program.

Comment: Huh, never used runghc. Doesn't it work with that too? As far as I know runghc passes its arguments on to ghc.

Comment: hammar was right, I was putting -i after the name of the file. It works fine

Comment: I can't seem to get it working with cabal. I don't really know anything about the format of cabal files, but I put `examples.cabal` in `doc/examples` with the single line: `hs-source-dirs: ../../src`. I then tried `runghc Example1.hs` and it says it can't find the module. I also tried `runghc doc/examples/Example1.hs` from the root of the project. Do I need more stuff in the cabal file? Different name? Pass a flag to ghc?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: You can run `cabal init` to get help with setting up a basic `.cabal` file. After that, add the `Hs-source-dirs` to the appropriate `Executable` section (or `Library` if you're building a library).

Comment: With the `.cabal` file, you need to fill out a lot of fields and then do something like `$ cabal configure; $ cabal build` to compile `Example1.hs` (and other example/test modules. Not suitable for runghc.

Comment: Creating a new, separate cabal project just for examples, and having the result only work in a subdirectory of the larger cabal project, seems like a strange idea to me.

Comment: That all makes sense. I didn't really expect ghc to be aware of cabal files. It's too bad there's no way to put some config somewhere that will make a straight-up `runghc doc/examples/Example1.hs` to work, but I'll survive. Thanks!

Comment: @ehird Depends. Certainly unusual, but if you have an ongoing project in development with frequent updates, it saves some typing to create a separate test package and just need a `cabal build` to update.

Comment: For runghc, make sure you put no space between the -i option and the path or it gets confused. E.g. `runghc -isrc/ example.hs`